# Excel Finding a Range

Tags: microsoft-excel

I feel silly, because this should be easy, but I can't figure this out.

I have a series of columns of data. It always starts at row number 11, and is always in columns E,F,G,H,I, and K. The problem is I never know what the length of each series is. Sometimes each series is more than 100 entries, more commonly about 30 each. They are not in tables and cannot be.

I want to create a drop down on another sheet, using the data validation method, not a combobox, for each series. While I can put in a range like "C11:C999" this creates large blank areas on the dropdown which is annoying.

I was toying with something with "=COUNTA" to count the number of non-blank cells and add 10 to determine the cell address to reference in a range, but I couldn't seem to pull that off either.

Comment: In the Data Validation dialog box, did you make sure "Ignore Blank" is unchecked?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with `COUNTA`.
Data validation will only allow a single column, so this solution will only list the first column E.

The formula `=Sheet1!$E$11:INDEX(Sheet1!$E:$E,COUNTA(Sheet1!$E:$E)+10)` will list your data in column E as long as there aren't any gaps in the data in column E.
If you place the formula directly into data validation you'll get this message:
[image]

The workaround is to create the formula as a named range.  `Formulas > Name Manager` on the toolbar.
You can then reference that in your data validation.
[image]

Comment: This worked kind of well. It listed 4 extra blank cells as zero...I tried deleting any possible contents in those cells but no luck

Comment: By setting a defined range, like E11:E999, it solves the issue. not sure why. I didn't specify that the range cannot be more than 1000 entries. but here's the question: I will have to place this formula in a cell, then reference it correct?

Comment: Also, you need to add the '#' symbol at the end

Comment: No, just create the formula in the named range dialog box.  If you're getting blank cells at the end then it could be the `+10` needs adjusting or the column that the `COUNTA` function is looking at contains blanks in the dataset - have it look at a column with no blanks.  Not sure why you'd need a # at the end as it's not a spilled range.